# Get user activity for specific site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, site-collection, information-management

Is there anyway to get user activity within a date range for a given SharePoint site collection?

Seems like the Management API get's for all SharePoint only. It needs to be from C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly target a particular site collection but what you can do it use is Audit.SharePoint content type filter while make REST API call.

```
https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/{tenant GUID}/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.SharePoint&amp;startTime=2017-06-17&amp;endTime=2017-06-19
```

Once you have data from above service you can use filter based on SharePoint Base API Schema with parameter Site, you might have to use Site Id as parameter to filter events specifics to a particular SharePoint site collectoin.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-schema#sharepoint-base-schema

Comment: Thanks this might be durable. I will make a test. I would expect an extreme high amount of data, but let me test. Thanks for your response I will followup and reply later.